# How to make that in 5 seconds after the capture of the base was a transition to the main menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to make that in 5 seconds after the capture of the base was a transition to the main menu? Here my cod.

```c#
        private void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Timer(5f));
    }

IEnumerator Timer(float time)
{
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        if (ImagePoint.fillAmount == 1f)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well add some condition to say base captured? or add this component to it when it is? choice is yours dear its your game

Answer (score 0):

Add something along the lines of this into your gameplay scene:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
  
  // ... imagine the rest of your game management logic is here

  ///<summary>has the base been captured yet?</summary>
  private bool _baseCaptured = false;

  ///<summary>name of main menu scene</summary>
  [SerializeField]
  private string _mainMenuSceneName = "MainMenu";

  ///<summary> delay before going to main menu once base has been captured</summary>
  [SerializeField]
  private float mainMenuDelaySeconds = 5f;


  ///<summary>Call this method when the base has been captured</summary>
  public void BaseHasBeenCaptured()
  {
    if(_baseCaptured){ return; }

    _baseCaptured = true;

    Debug.Log($"the base has been captured, will go to main menu in {mainMenuDelaySeconds } seconds");

    StartCoroutine(GoToMainMenuCoroutine(mainMenuDelaySeconds);
    
  }

  ///<summary>Goes to the main menu scene after delay seconds</summary>
  private IEnumerator GoToMainMenuCoroutine(float delay)
  {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    SceneManager.LoadScene(_mainMenuSceneName);
  }
}
```

Then, as soon as the base is captured (however that happens), you would simply need to call this in order to return to the main menu after a delay of 5 seconds:

```csharp
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>.BaseHasBeenCaptured();
```

Of course, there are much more elegant ways of doing this (such as by invoking an event which the GameManager is subscribed to in order to handle things), but, as those more refined answers would first require information about the overall system architecture of your game, this quick-and-dirty solution should work in the meantime.